# How to get notified when no record is inserted in a table for a while in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, triggers

**Goal:** I have a table which handles the status of a device. Whenever I don't receive the status from it for one hour or more, I want to get notified once.

The device inserts a "heartbeat" record in the table with a timestamp (NOTE: I have to stick with this implementation).

In order to get notified for any changes, I'm using a service with a queue (which is read by another program).

**What I've tried**: I made a job which runs every 1 minute. It:

- Looks at the last heartbeat in the table
- If the timestamp is one hour ago or before:

  - Looks in another table which stores if I have already written the notification on the queue or not
  - If not, writes in the queue
- Else:

  - Looks in another table which stores if I have already written the notification on the queue or not
  - If yes, resets the value to no

**Issues with that**: I'm concerned about my technique for executing some code when no record is inserted in a while:

1. I feel like there is a built in (and better) way to solve this kind of problems, but I can't find it;
2. It doesn't notify me as soon as possible (in the worst case, after 1 minute). This could be solved by reducing the schedule wait time, but I don't know if it may hurt performances or not. I would want the lighter solution possible;
3. I don't like to have to use an helper table, so I would want to remove it;
4. I would prefer to not use jobs if possible (I'm using a VS DB project and I would like to remove the post deployment script).

Comment: so whats the code youve tried?

Comment: @DougCoats Does it make the question easier to understand? The core logic is already explained in "What I've done", so I felt like putting the full code was redundant, unnecessary and (as the code is more complex) useless... . Is there anything specific which is incomplete or unclear and that I should clarify?